# how to upgrade Maven in Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven

Im very new to Maven and its depressing when i even spent hours only to update my Maven version. I need to upgrade it because [this](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer) plugin and eclipse's plugin need Maven 3.11+ to get working.

I installed it by simply use :

```
sudo apt-get install maven
```

And this is the version i got :

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4
```

I tried to update it by using :

```
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install maven
```

but it said that my maven is already up to date.

Then i found [this](https://launchpad.net/~natecarlson/+archive/maven3) PPA, but unfortunately this PPA dont have any Marven for Saucy (13.10).

Please help me, Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you simply download the version of maven that you need and then put in in PATH?

Comment: It returns 'mvn: /usr/bin/mvn /usr/bin/X11/mvn /usr/share/man/man1/mvn.1.gz' when i run 'whereis mvn', do you mean i just need to move the new maven in those paths?

Comment: @BlazeTama download maven 3.11, unzip it to : /opt; then put this path: "/opt/apache-maven-3.11/bin" to PATH variable. This is how you edit your path: http://askubuntu.com/questions/3744/how-do-i-modify-my-path-so-that-the-changes-are-available-in-every-terminal-sess

Comment: Thanks for your help, i finally install it manually LOL. Will it be okay if i install it in another directory? I installed it in usr/local

Comment: @BlazeTama yup, it's ok.